# How to change cell backcolor in devexpress grid by cell value?

Tags: c#, colors, devexpress, cell, xtragrid

I'm trying to solve how to change cell backcolor by it's value ? for example, column name - Colors, and columns rows value is color name - red, yellow, blue and etc. So I want to know how to change cell backcolor by value. If cell value is - red, then I want cell backcolor be red.

Thanks

Comment: I was having a idea where you can get every cell value and set cell appearance backcolor to Color.FromName(cellvalue). But I'm struggling for getting cell values. Don't know how get column (COLOR) all cells values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`GridView.CustomDrawCell`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CustomDrawCelltopic) event. You can get the column from `e.Column` property, and you can get the cell value from `e.CellValue`.
Here is example:

```
private void gridView1_CustomDrawCell(object sender, RowCellCustomDrawEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Column.FieldName == "Colors")
        try
        {
            e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.FromName(e.CellValue.ToString());
            e.Appearance.Options.UseBackColor = true;
        }
        catch { }
}
```

Comment: @ryterys What is the version of your DevExpress?

Comment: Currently at here it is - 12.2

Comment: @ryterys My version is 15.1. Try to use: `e.Appearance.FillRectangle(e.Cache, e.Bounds); e.Appearance.DrawString(e.Cache, e.DisplayText, e.Bounds);` instead of `e.DefaultDraw();`.

Comment: @ryterys Also you can try to change back color and to not handle the custom draw.